# Auto fill date text box when matching signature is entered

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have created a pdf form in bluebeam extreme, essentially it is a list of fields to add signatures and next to each signature is a text box for the date. 
When someone opens the pdf and adds their signature I want the current date to automatically be entered into the matching date field. E.g when sign1 is populated with a signature I want date1 to have the date that signature was added.
I need this date to stay as the date the signature was added and not change to the current date when the pdf is opened again as not all signatures will be added on the same data.
Thank you in advance for you assistance.

Comment: You may want to add an ActionScript tag. Creating a date object and writing a formatted string isn't tough, however doing it in a PDF for only those signatures that haven't been added yet is likely peculiar to [ActionScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript.html).

Answer (score 0):

To get the date use the following script

- Name a text box form field "Today".
- Open the Properties of that form field.
- Under Format, choose Custom as the Category and then click Edit.
- Enter this JavaScript and then click OK.

var f = this.getField("Today");

f.value = util.printd("mmm/d/yyyy", new Date());

http://communities.bluebeam.com/showthread.php?t=4598&highlight=javascript+text+format

The problem with this is that the date will always update itself every time the clock date changes. To update the field once follow this forum post
http://communities.bluebeam.com/showthread.php?5093-Validating-Number-Fields-and-importing-the-current-date

Clear the text from the field and make the pdf form read only. This will input the current date only once into each pdf.